# What files get erased when installing Ubuntu by erasing my current Windows OS

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my desktop. I have the installation file disk ready to install. But, I want to know which of my files ( only windows files or all my personal files as well ) will get erased if I choose to install Ubuntu by erasing my current OS ( Windows 7 ).

Comment: Everything will be erased.

Answer (score 3):

**Everything** on the disk will be erased.

Every single last file.

Even the MBR.

---

However, if you would like to save your files, you can do that easily. There are two ways of doing so:

1. Install Ubuntu in a dual-boot with Win 7 (this is an option in the installer).
2. Buy an external USB hard drive, and drag&drop your `C:\Users\youruser` folder onto it. Then, after installing Ubuntu, you can plug in the external disk, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> everything in the documents folder, and drag them in Ubuntu's documents folder. You can do the same for the pictures and videos folders.

Comment: in both cases you should **do a backup** of your data if you are manipulating hard-drives/partitions/OS!

Answer (score 1):

The whole drive will get cleared if you do this.

You're either going to have to backup all your personal files (presumably to external HDD) & do it, or else choose a dual boot option to re-size Windows, then copy/move files around, you can remove Windows later should you wish to & re-use the space.

The 'remove existing OS' does what it says, removes every bit of the old one. Windows does this by default without asking, so it's nice to be given the choice!

Comment: "Windows does this by default without asking" - Not so. I know from personal experience.

Comment: anyway... you should **do a backup** of your data in any case you are manipulating hard-drives/partitions/OS!